# Kubernetes with Vagrant nodes won't register

Tags: docker, vagrant, kubernetes

I have been going through this to get started with Kubernetes, running on Mac OS v 10.9.5, Vagrant v 1.7.4, VirtualBox v 4.3.28, and Kubernetes v 1.0.3.:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.md

Full install log can be found here:
http://mcdonaldland.info/files/kubernetes/install-log.txt

I've tried both the download and sh install versions of this.

I've run this multiple times and every time it gets to the "waiting for each minion to be registered with cloud provider" step and loops forever. Eventually, I "CTRL+C" and exit the script. In looking at the source it obviously has something to do with the nodes not being found, but I can't figure out why it cannot find them.

After killing the script, running 'kubectl get nodes' returns nothing. The same happens if I used the SH script.

If I am in the ~/kubernetes/cluster director and run 'vagrant ssh master' or 'vagrant ssh minion-1' I can connect to them. If I run some scripts to add pods I can get them to register. Same with Replication Controllers.

When I check status the pods will never start. When I dig into the logs it appears that the nodes cannot be connected to (aka found) and the minions are erroring on startup.

I have been struggling for 5 days now to figure out why my nodes are not showing up / registering properly. I figure I'm missing something simple but am at a loss now.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same issue today. If I run kube-up.sh with `VAGRANT_LOG=error` I get: `ERROR loader: Unknown config sources: [:"28363960_vm_master__virtualbox"]`. I'll file an issue with the kubernetes guys to see what we can get.

Comment: This seems to be the issue we're interested in. Please upvote so it gets some attention: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12854

Comment: Good find. I didn't find that one in my search and filed this last night: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12892. I just commented on it indicating potential overlap.

Comment: It doesn't matter - I can't get it to recognize the nodes at all. The pods themselves will spin up regardless of image I use but they won't talk back and forth so never reach "ready" state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for the issue that you encountered.

A fix for the issue reported is opened as a pull request here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/13224

Once merged, you should be able get node registration to work.  There was a leading space character in the YAML file for the kubelet kubeconfig that was the source of the problem.

If you do not want to wait for the referenced PR to land, the issue is already resolved in our master branch.

Comment: This works for me using 1.0.3. Same tactic as the other answer - download then overwrite these 3 files in the /kubernetes/cluster/vagrant dir. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The reason is a bug in kubernetes. It [seems to be a TLS error](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12854).

If you manually download [kubernetes 1.0.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.0.1) you will get closer. However, there's been a bugfix that you'll need to patch into 1.0.1 to make it work properly with vagrant. Otherwise, network provisioning will not work and you'll run into [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12285#issuecomment-128613056).

So, as suggested there, apply [these changes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12237/files) to the provision scripts of v1.0.1 and you'll be good to go. Simple, right?

Comment: Simple... I'll give this a shot tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Mi "simple" remark was actually ironic. I thought the set up would be more automagical :)

Comment: It would be typically - without a bug. All in all, this was a pretty simple work around until a fix can be applied. Good call and thanks!

Comment: Updating the 'right' answer to reflect the fix now available.